# how do include multiple pieces of data on one page?

Tags: php, database

I cant figure out how to get multiple entries of data from my database. You can see below that I have `newsID = 1`, which allows me to get that to show on my database, but how should I change the code to be able to access other entries like `newsID = 2` as well?

```
<?php
$queryAffinity = "SELECT * FROM affnews WHERE newsID = 1";
$stmt = $pdo->query($queryAffinity);
$row = $stmt->fetchObject();
?>




<?php if($row->newsID == 1) echo "<p>{$row->newsDescription}</p>"; ?>
```

this is the code im trying to use to echo the id 1

Comment: quite a few ways to do this actually

Comment: i am still unable to figure out how to select a specific id the display with echo

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `WHERE`-Clause and put it in a loop. For example:

```
$queryAffinity = "SELECT * FROM affnews WHERE newsID = 1 OR newsID = 2";
$stmt = $pdo->query($queryAffinity);
while($row = $stmt->fetchObject())
{
    //do something with $row
}
```

Comment: i'm not so familiar with loops but thanks ill try to figure it out!

Comment: or remove the `WHERE`-Clause to output all rows !

Answer (score 0):

You Can use the following code:

```
$queryAffinity = "SELECT * FROM affnews WHERE newsID IN (1, 2)";
$stmt = $pdo->query($queryAffinity);
while($row = $stmt->fetchObject())
{
    echo $row->id;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, how do i select a specific ID when using echo ?

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer. That way the OP might actually learn _why_ this is a good suggestion (and might even be able to reuse it for other things).

Comment: Use `if($row->id == 1) echo 'one';`

Comment: before i had the code, but this wont work now as
                  echo "<h1>{$row->newsHeader}</h1>";
                  echo "<p>{$row->newsDescription}</p>";
I have tried this but i have something wrong if($row->id == 1) echo "<h1>{$row->newsHeader}</h1>";

Comment: i dont know how to indent comments sorry about that :(

Comment: Does the field `id` exist?

Comment: i have tried changing it to newsID but that does also not work, newsID is a row in my database

Comment: This just give me a 1 displaying at the top of my screen                           <?php if($row->newsID == 1) echo "<p>{$row->newsDescription}</p>";
 ?>